# Flipping a PPM Image in C

Tags: c

I came to you all earlier with an issue that was just a simple mistake, so I'm hoping eyes looking over this will be the same.

This is in C

I have to flip a PPM image horizontally, but my current code either draws a Segmentation Fault or does not actually flip anything.

The code I use that draws the Segmentation Fault is:

```
int a, b, x, y;
x = 3 * myPic->rows;
y = 3 * myPic->cols;
for(a = 0; a < (y / 2); a++) {
    for(b = 0; b < x; b++) {
        Pixel temp = myPic->pixels[a][b];
        myPic->pixels[a][b] = myPic->pixels[y - a - 1][b];
        myPic->pixels[y - a - 1][b] = temp;
    }
}
return myPic;
```

}

The code that returns no change is:

```
int a, b, x, y;
for(a = 0; a < myPic->rows; a++) {
    for(b = 0; b < myPic->cols; b++) {
        Pixel temp = myPic->pixels[a][b];
        myPic->pixels[a][b] = myPic->pixels[myPic->cols - a - 1][b];
        myPic->pixels[myPic->cols - a - 1][b] = temp;
    }
}
return myPic;
```

Because PPM images have RGB values, I assume that the row and column values should be multiplied by three. And I thought that going all the way across would cause it to go back to the original so i divided the width (columns) by two. I'm stuck and I hope this is a small mistake, can anyone help?

Comment: you're running off the end of the image. `myPic->pixels[a][b]` goes boom because `a` and `b` are set to top out at THREE TIMES the size of the image. you can't just start accessing array indexes that don't exist.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense...Should I reallocate myPic->pixels[a][b] to be three times bigger? How would I even do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is bad, it accesses the array out of it's boundaries. Your second code is better although it flips the image then it reflips it back.

And just to straight things out, number of rows is picture height, number of columns is picture width, the first index in the 2-d arrays is row selection (height index), and the second index is colum selection (width index). Horizontal flip exchanges pixels from left to right.
Vertical flip exchanges pixel from top to bottom.

Having that, This should be a horizontal flip

```
int row, col;
for(row = 0; row < myPic->rows; row++) {
    for(col = 0; col < myPic->cols / 2 ; col++) { /*notice the division with 2*/
        Pixel temp = myPic->pixels[row][col];
        myPic->pixels[row][col] = myPic->pixels[row][myPic->cols - col -1];
        myPic->pixels[row][myPic->cols - col -1] = temp;
    }
}
return myPic;
```

After you modify the image in memory, you need to save it, or redraw the modified image with the graphic library you are using.

Comment: Okay I understand how I have gone past the boundaries, but I tried the code you used and it returns the same image as before

Comment: This results in a flipped, but very spotty image...some sections of the image have seemingly every other line fixed